# Checking if time equals a time with duration

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, time, pdo

So I am creating a food delivery system. I want to check, if a time is taken. The problem is that there is a duration associated with some times. It is pretty easy to do so if there is no duration.

**WORKING CODE EXAMPLE:**

For example, here is my `deliveries` table:

```
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| id | delivery_date | delivery_time | duration |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| 1  | 2018-02-18    | 10:30:00      | null     |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
```

Let's say my selected delivery time is `2018-02-18 10:30:00`, then it will be taken. The code is:

```
$deliveryDate = '2018-02-18';
$deliveryTime = '10:30:00';

$stmt = "SELECT id FROM deliveries WHERE appointment_date = :date AND appointment_time = :time";
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $deliveryDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':time', $deliveryTime);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();

if($result) {
    echo 'Sorry, this is already taken!';
}
```

That code is working.

---

**NOT WORKING CODE EXAMPLE:**

I'm trying to find out if I change the `duration` from `null` to `40` (40 minutes), it would need to block out `2018-02-18 10:30:00 to 11:10:00`.

Let's say the duration is 40 (minutes) and the `delivery_time` is `11:05:00`. It should block it out.

```
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| id | delivery_date | delivery_time | duration |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+
| 1  | 2018-02-18    | 10:30:00      | 40       |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------+

$deliveryDate = '2018-02-18';
$deliveryTime = '11:05:00';

$stmt = "SELECT id FROM deliveries WHERE appointment_date = :date AND appointment_time = :time";
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $deliveryDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':time', $deliveryTime);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();

if($result) {
    echo 'Sorry, this is already taken!';
}
```

How can I make it take the duration into account?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like a simple case of setting a minimum (`delivery_time`) and maximum (plus `duration`) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine the date and time column to a `datetime` you can use `timestampadd()` to add the duration and then check if the given date and time is in the period.

```
SELECT id
       FROM deliveries
       WHERE cast(concat(delivery_date, ' ', delivery_time) AS datetime) <= cast(concat(:date, ' ', :time) AS datetime)
             AND timestampadd(minute, duration, cast(concat(delivery_date, ' ', delivery_time) AS datetime)) > cast(concat(:date, ' ', :time) AS datetime);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19c89e9515bddf8242392956a4fc1eeb)

You could make your life easier if you just used two `datetime`s here instead of splitting it in three columns. Then you could also benefit from indexes.

Comment: Losing the possibility to use indexes (if they're there of course) can be quite a huge thing in terms of performance.